# Can use taxonomies to I build a list of "conditions" that can be added to and referenced from different nodes?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I need to build a list of "conditions" that can be added to and references from different nodes. "Conditions" have a title and body. This screamed taxonomy but what's stopping me is that the "conditions" need the ability to modify the body field on a node-by-node basis.

It's a bit difficult to explain but I need:

1. A library of content that can be referenced and can grow, like taxonomy.
2. When referenced, the content has to be able to be modified but only that instance (don't modify the referenced entity site-wide). This will will be like an override for the reference.

I can to the first part with taxonomies but don't know how to override on a node-by-node basis as it's just a reference. It seems as if the referenced entity needs to populate a field on the node, and there it can be overwritten.

EDIT: Found the solution using this: https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill. I added a long text field on my taxonomy and my content and mapped them together.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "need the ability to modify the body field on a node-by-node basis"?

Comment: Basically have canned text but allow users to modify it on the node that is referencing it and not update the canned text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can get this done with taxonomies. However I would recommend you to have a look at either of those modules also (or "instead"?):

- [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).
- [Entity connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityconnect).

These 2 modules are also recommended in the (illuminating) article "[Relativity Model for Drupal](http://jay-epstein.com/relativity/overview)", for which this is an introduction to it (quoted from this linked page):

> The Relativity Data Model for Drupal is a zero-custom-code, collection of steps, procedures and methods that strive to help site builders, users and site visitors interact with Drupal in a far easier and more efficient way. This is done by:
>
> - Data architecture and data modeling merging as a single step through a documentation procedure.
> - Customized user interfaces that cater to individual workflows throughout permission roles.
> - Multi-level relational data structures that relate to other multi-level relational structures.
> - Mimicking the concept of database joins within Drupal's UI's.
>   Vastly reducing the size of Drupal sites by a small handful of modules that provide greater power, speed and expansion capabilities.

The small handful of modules (cfr. the last bullet) is detailed on [Interface elegance and experience](http://jay-epstein.com/relativity/interface-elegance-and-experience).

Comment: Thanks, but how would this be different than taxonomies? They are an entity as well that are referenced. My challenge is that I need to be able to modify the taxonomy's body field on the node referencing it and not update the taxonomy itself. ER and EC update the referenced entity.